# Particle Current Density in GR

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, kinetic-theory

**TL;DR**

Why is there a **measure** in the definition of particle current density?

**Background** 
I found myself studying kinetic physics in general relativity, which is fairly well documented in [this livingreviews article](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2011-4/). Kinetic physics, in this case, refers to switching from "particle description" into a "phase space description" and formulating general relativistic equations there. The only difference between these two descriptions is that one can think of "phase space" as a sort of probability distribution, and it can be used to derive macroscopic (large scale) equations with various approximations in some sense easier.

**Question** In [the notes given above](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2011-4/), they simply "define" particle current density (non-numbered equation) as:

$N^a=-\int_{\mathcal{R}^3} f \sqrt{|g_{ab}|} p^a \frac{dp^1 dp^2 dp^3}{p_0}$

For which $N^0$ is supposedly the "general relativistic equivalent" of number density. I find myself disagreeing with this definition (in particular I am fixated on the term $|g_{ab}|$), as I tried solving it for Schwarzschild geometry.

For Schwarzschild geometry:

$N^0=\int_{\mathcal{R}^3} f \cdot (r^2 \sin\theta) \cdot p^0 \frac{dp^1 dp^2 dp^3}{E}$, where $E$ is the covariant energy.

Now I do not understand why there is a factor $\sqrt{|g_{ab}|}$ describing the volume element, because in this case I do not see how $N^0$ can describe density.

The way I understand each term:

- $f(x^\mu, p^\mu)$ describes the probability **density**
- $(r^2 \sin\theta)$ describes the effect of infinitesimal volume element
- $p^0$ describes the time dilation in GR
- $E$ I dont really understand why this is here but it seems to cancel $p^0$ when in local lorentz frame so why not.

Now obviously $(r^2 \sin\theta)$ means multiplication by a volume element (easiest to understand as $dV = r^2 \sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$ in spherical coordinates, forgetting GR for a while).

If $f$ already describes density, why is there an additional volume element?

**Definitions**

- $f$ is the phase space density
- $\sqrt{|g_{ab}|}|$ is the square root of determinant
- $p^a$ is the 4-momentum of a given particle.

Comment: Do you want f to be a top degree form or a function? They can be identified but usually people use the function rather than the intrinsic differential form.

Comment: @AHusain I'd like it to be function

Comment: You can't integrate functions without saying the measure.

Comment: @AHusain Hmm, then how about also dividing by the square root of the determinant twice? I suppose you may be correct, but the resulting integral still doesn't seem to physically make sense, since for example it says that for a Schwarzschild black hole if the phase space density is constant along $\theta$ and $\phi$ direction, then the number density closer to the poles is much smaller -- as opposed to also being constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition of $N^\alpha$ looks a bit fishy to me to be honest: In "On the Topology and Future Stability of the Universe" Sec. 7.1.1 (available on [google books](https://books.google.de/books?id=uVdHNP7vs34C&pg=PA87&dq=Vlasov%20matter%20current%20density&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSmZCw1-fOAhUBkiwKHXXdBIgQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=Vlasov%20matter%20current%20density&f=false)) it is defined as: $$N^\alpha=\int_{P_\xi} f p^\alpha \mu_{_{P_\xi}}.$$ The description of $\mu_{_{P_\xi}}$ in that book sounds overly complicated to me but in sec. 5.3 "Collisionless Matter" of Numerical Relativity of T. W. Baumgarte there are several realtions for $\mu$ to $d^3V_p$ and  $d^4V_p$ depending on what one understands under $f$:

$$N^\alpha=\int p^\alpha \frac {F} m d^4V_p=\int p^\alpha \frac F {p^t} \frac{dmdp_1dp_2dp_3}{\sqrt{-g}},$$
with $F$ as number density in phase space/ distribution function defined by: $$F(x^\alpha,p_\beta)=\frac{dN}{d^3V_x d^4V_p}.$$

Here with a lorentzian metric $(-+++)$ and $$d^4V_p=\frac{-dp_t dp_1dp_2dp_3}{\sqrt{-g}}=\frac{m}{p^t}\frac{dm dp_1dp_2dp_3}{\sqrt{-g}},$$ 
$$d^3V_x=\frac{p^t} m \sqrt{-g} dx_1dx_2dx_3.$$
The $p^t$ in the denominator comes from the substitution $dp_t=-\frac{m}{p^t}dm.$

If one only describes particles with identical rest mass $m_0$ one can define $f$ with:
$$F(x^\alpha,p_\beta)=f(x^\alpha,p_i)\delta(m-m_0)\Leftrightarrow f(x^\alpha,p_i)=\frac{dN}{d^3V_x d^3V_p}$$
and $N^\alpha$ becomes:
$$N^\alpha=\int p^\alpha \frac f {p^t} \frac{dp_1dp_2dp_3}{\sqrt{-g}}.$$

A kind of disclaimer at the end: I "derived" the equations for $N^\alpha$ by looking at the expressions for the energy momentum tensor (given in Baumgarte's book) but this should be fine since the ony difference seems to be one $p^\beta$. For a detailed explanation I would recommend reading that section 5.3.

So so summarize I would say $\sqrt{-g}$ should be in the denominator at least if one defines $F$ and $f$ the way I presented.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That clarified some of my doubts; I actually put the $\sqrt{-g}$ in the denominator at first since I thought it seemed physical. But then I read the kinetic physics article and got confused.